# How to write out the defining equations of subvarieties of Grassmannians?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For example, in Harris's book Algebraic Geometry, it is said that the subset of $\Sigma_l(\Lambda) \subset \mathbb{G}(k,\mathbb{P}V)$ of $k$-planes that meet a given $m$-dimensional linear subspace $\Lambda$ in a subspace of dimension of at least $l$ can be described as the locus $$\Sigma_l(\Lambda) = \{[\omega]:\omega \wedge v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_{m-l+1} = 0 ; \forall v_1, \ldots , v_{m-l+1} \in \Lambda \}.$$ Clearly, this is not a polynomial relation. My guess is that I'm supposed to use a similar argument as in the proof that the Grassmannian is a projective variety via the Plücker embedding. I want to say that each of these $[\omega] \in \Sigma_l(\Lambda)$ corresponds to a map $$\phi_{[\omega]} : \bigwedge^{m-l+1}\Lambda \to \bigwedge^{k + m - l + 1}V\\$$

$$v \mapsto \omega \wedge v $$ with $\Lambda$ identified as a subspace of $V$. And then go on to say something about the vanishing of some minors of the matrix representation of this map.

Is this correct approach? Does this general argument work for any subvariety defined by the vanishing of some wedge product?

Also, is it true in general that two linear subspaces whose dimensions add up to less than $k$ intersect if and only if the wedge product of any choices of their bases vanish? If this is true, then could you not describe the subvariety (in the case l = 0) above in this way by taking only the $k$-planes whose wedge product with some basis for $\Lambda$ vanishes?

Comment: You can write everything using matrices. I think this is the usual approach when dealing with Grassmannians

Comment: What about for products of Grassmannians? Am I supposed to look at "bihomogeneous" wedge products to define subvarieties?

Comment: As I understand your question, you don't need to use anything about the product of Grassmannians. Also I don't understand your claim : "Clearly, this is not a polynomial relation."

Comment: I meant that the description inside the brackets is not a polynomial relation. The vanishing of a wedge product doesn't explicitly involve polynomials in terms of coordinates of the Plücker coordinates. What I am basically asking is if the vanishing of a wedge product can always be expressed as the vanishing of minors of some matrix in the above fashion. The bit about products is sort of an add-on. Does the vanishing of a wedge product also correspond to some polynomial relations? Do I need extra conditions on my wedge product in the case of products of Grassmannians?

Comment: the vanishing of the wedge product is equivalent to the vanishing of some determinants. The wedge product vanishes if any vector in the wedge product is not linearly independent with respect to the linear combination of the other vectors (in the wedge product). Just pick a basis of $\Lambda$ and complete the basis to get a basis for the vector space, write everything in this basis and expand the wedge product. The vanishing of that wedge product will be equivalent to a bunch of polynomials vanishing.

Comment: I don't like that this post is titled as "subvarieties of Grassmanians" but is entirely about Grassmanians as subvarieties embedded in projective space. Very misleading.